# Using R to download *.xls files generates error

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to download a large number of xls files from the BLS servers. 
When I manually download any of the files, they open perfectly.

But when I try to download the file from inside R:

```
library(readxl)

tp <- "http://www.bea.gov/histdata/Releases/GDP_and_PI/2014/Q4/Third_March-27-2015/Section1ALL_Hist.xls"
temp <- paste0(tempfile(), ".xls")
download.file(tp, destfile = temp, mode = "wb")
```

this downloads a file of the right size, but attempting to read the file:

```
 data <- read_excel(path = temp, sheet = 1)
```

returns the error

```
seek: wanted to seek to sector 5374034 (0x520052) loc=2751505920
```

Comment: Does it actually open in excel?

Comment: `temp <- paste0(tempfile(), ".xls")` might work.

Comment: When I download the file manually, yes, it opens in Excel. When I download the file in R, it won't open in Excel or be read by R.

Comment: @plafort thanks for the suggestion--I added it the to question. still returns an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `mode="wb"` to do a binary transfer:

```
download.file(tp, destfile=temp, mode="wb")
```

Comment: Odd, this worked for me. I was also able to use `download.file(tp, destfile=temp, method='curl')`. What's your OS and such?

Comment: gosh, I just refreshed my R session and it worked. Thanks for pushing me!